# SharePoint 2013 Search Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have built a SharePoint 2013 environment and everything was successfully setup. Then I had to disconnect the SharePoint 2013 server from the Farm, then I reconnected it to the farm again using the SharePoint 2013 products configuration wizard, then I re-run the AutoSPInstaller script I used to install SharePoint 2013 originally and this time the search service application was not successfully  provisioned (already provisioned during initial install via AutoSPInstaller).

In search service application search administration page, I get the following message under "Search Application Topology":

"Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running"

Has anyone come across this issue before? how was it resolved?

I have installed the required/additional hotfixes: KB2472264, KB2554876, KB2708075, KB2765317...

Would deleting the Search Service Application and the database (data) associated with it via central admin, then running the AutoSPInstaller script again fix this issue? has anybody tries this method?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated... I am tearing my hair out at this minute...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much researching on the internet, the one thing that resolved this issue was to delete the search service application via central admin altogether and then re-provisioning it again. In my occasion this was provisioned via "AutoSPInstaller" which did the trick and resolved the message:

"Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running"

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove corrupt search service applications:

http://pointsforsharing.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5

2.Run `powershell script:`

```
$hostA = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "YourServerName"
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $hostA
$UP = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.TypeName -like "Usage*"}
$UP.Provision()
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance –Identity $hostA
$hostA
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this working by installing these updates BEFORE INSTALLING SHAREPOINT. If I install these updates after installing SharePoint, I don't have much luck with this..